# Admin SDK directory api returning member type equal to "CUSTOMER"

Tags: java, gdata, google-admin-sdk, google-directory-api

I am trying to get all the members of a group using Directory API of Google Admin SDK.I have added all the users of my domain to this group using **add all users in this domain** button on admin panel of my domain. Apart from this I have also added one more user to this group. Hence there are two entries for this group. Directory API returns the following member list.

```
{
"kind": "admin#directory#members",
"etag": "\"geb3xcv_ZSaV25Ofefv5dh58nnk/LqxcrE5TnEAIfsL40kOhNX3fA8Y\"",
"members": 
    [
        {
            "kind": "admin#directory#member",
            "etag": "\"geb3xcv_ZSaV25Ofefv5dh58nnk/kmhESKx70CkHpkdZmsTYGx6wdNs\"",
            "id": "C037672zf5r",
            "role": "MEMBER",
            "type": "CUSTOMER"
        },
        {
            "kind": "admin#directory#member",
            "etag": "\"geb3xcv_ZSaV25Ofefv5dh58nnk/FVfFaFMLGYQMa2Ly8XA7uLEPLD8\"",
            "id": "118196612we999272349516",
            "email": "notadmin@xyz.com",
            "role": "MEMBER",
            "type": "USER"
        }
    ]
```

}

**Member type for the first member is CUSTOMER**. In document it has been mentioned that possible value for "type" attributes are **GROUP, MEMBER** and acceptable values are **GROUP,USER**.

What is the meaning of type **CUSTOMER** here. Will it returns **type** equal to customer for a member (shared with all users in domain).

Answer (score 1):

Though this is not really documented, but what you say is very likely -- I also have added all users in my app org to a group, and getting a member **type: CUSTOMER.**

```
 "kind": "admin#directory#members",
 "etag": "\"geb3xXXXXXXXX\"",
 "members": [
  {
   "kind": "admin#directory#member",
   "etag": "\"geb3xcvXXXXXXXX\"",
   "id": "C0XXXXXXXX",
   "role": "MEMBER",
   "type": "CUSTOMER"
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is documented here regarding the meaning and use of customerId: https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-users.html#get_all_users

I found it hidden here: https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users

Now, the remaining question for which I didnt find documentation is: can a domain have more than one customerId? If so, it would be safe to assume that if a group contains such type "CUSTOMER", we know all domain users are part of it, even in multi-domain gapps scenarios.
Otherwise, seems painful to have to query the user manually against the "all users" api in my first link.

Answer (score 1):

I found the same thing when using the Directory API. After much discussions with Google Enterprise Support, I got confirmation that the values for 'type' of a member resource is:
 'GROUP'     Member is another group
 'USER'      Member is a user
 'CUSTOMER'  Member represents every user in the domain (akin to 'Everyone' i AD)

They promised that the documentation would (eventually) be updated to reflect this.